# Cabinet footprint cheaper tile

Tags: tile, cabinets

I'm using pretty expensive tile for my kitchen but feel stupid to cover invisible parts of the floor with it, such as under the cabinet footprint. Is it common to use cheaper but equally thick tile under cabinets, to save expensive tiles?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to saving money, there are a bunch of reasons to put cabinets directly on the subfloor and not put tiles under the cabinets:

- (As already answered by Lee Sam): Level the cabinets with shims and use the tile (or baseboard molding if the tile is not very thick) to hide the bottom edge of the cabinets
- If any plumbing or electrical needs to run through the floor, it is easier to do so without being concerned about tile or finished flooring
- Tile could be installed with different tiles around the edges, treating the installed cabinets like a wall.
- If you ever decide to replace the flooring in the future, there is no need to remove the cabinets (which can be quite involved due to sinks, dishwashers, heavy countertops, etc.) in order to replace the tiles underneath the cabinets.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, cabinets are set on the subfloor and the tile is installed up to the cabinet base.

This allows you to shim the cabinets to get them exactly level, and then cover (hide) the shims with the tile.